# Writing Python XML ElementTree output to CSV

Tags: python, csv, elementtree

TL;DR
I'm now able to output the information I want in the CSV but I'm just repeating the last XML file's data over and over again.

This is the latest version of the script:

```
import csv
import glob
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
filenames = glob.glob("..\Lib\macros\*.xml")

for filename in filenames:

  with open(filename, 'r') as content:
    element = ET.parse(content)
    root = element.getroot()
    print(root.attrib, filename)
  e = element.findall('commands/MatrixSwitch/')
  for i in e:
    print (i.tag, i.text)


    with open('results.csv', 'w', newline='') as file:
        for filename in filenames:
            writer = csv.writer(file)
            writer.writerow([root.attrib, filename])
            for i in e:
                writer.writerow([i.tag, i.text])
```

Say I have 10 XML files, I'm getting the output related to XML "File 10" 10 times in the CSV, not anything for XML "File 1-9" ... sure its something simple?

=========================================================================

I've written a small script which ingests a folder of XML files, searches for a particular element and then recalls some of the data. This is then printed to the console and written to a CSV, except I'm having trouble formatting my CSV correctly.

This is where I've got so far:

```
import csv
import glob
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
filenames = glob.glob("..\Lib\macros\*.xml")

for filename in filenames:

  with open(filename, 'r') as content:
    element = ET.parse(content)
    root = element.getroot()
    print(root.attrib, filename)
  e = element.findall('commands/MatrixSwitch/')
  for i in e:
    print (i.tag, i.text)
  with open('results.csv', 'w', newline='') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerow([root.attrib, filename])
```

I'm looking to capture the following data:

- XML Filename
- Macro Name
- Monitor ID
- Camera ID

I'm only interested in the  and  when a "Matrix Switch" is referred to in the XML. Sometimes there might only be one monitor ID and one camera ID, sometimes there might be more so the script needs to loop through and get all of the IDs within the "Matrix Switch" element. This seems to work so far.

Typical XML structure looks like this :

```
<macro name="NAME OF THE MACRO IS SHOWN HERE">
<execution>
<delay>0</delay>
</execution>
<parameters/>
<commands>
<MatrixSwitch>
<camera>1530</camera>
<monitor>1020</monitor>
</MatrixSwitch>
<MatrixSwitch>
<camera>1531</camera>
<monitor>1001</monitor>
</MatrixSwitch>
</commands>
</macro>
```

Or like this :

```
<macro name="ANOTHER NAME GOES HERE">
<execution>
<delay>0</delay>
</execution>
<parameters/>
<commands>
<MatrixSwitch>
<camera>201</camera>
<monitor>17</monitor>
</MatrixSwitch>
<MatrixSwitch>
<camera>206</camera>
<monitor>18</monitor>
</MatrixSwitch>
<MatrixSwitch>
<camera>202</camera>
<monitor>19</monitor>
</MatrixSwitch>
<MatrixSwitch>
<camera>207</camera>
<monitor>20</monitor>
</MatrixSwitch>
</commands>
</macro>
```

My current results.csv is only set to output the name and filename. This works but I'm unsure where I need to add the "writer" command to the loop where its dealing with the Monitor ID and Camera ID .

I want my CSV to show : Name, Filename, Monitor A, Camera A, Monitor B, Camera B, Monitor C, Camera C, Monitor D, Camera D etc.....

Any pointers greatly appreciated!!

Code has now been changed slightly :

```
import csv
import glob
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
filenames = glob.glob("..\Lib\macros\*.xml")

for filename in filenames:

  with open(filename, 'r') as content:
    element = ET.parse(content)
    root = element.getroot()
    print(root.attrib, filename)
  e = element.findall('commands/MatrixSwitch/')
  for i in e:
    print (i.tag, i.text)
    with open('results.csv', 'w', newline='') as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file)
        writer.writerow([root.attrib, filename])
        for i in e:
           writer.writerow([i.tag, i.text])
```

Output in the CSV is as below :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pm93Z.jpg

Comment: Welcome to stack. Please provide a [minimal, reproducible, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: That's all the code I have. If you c&p those two xml examples and call them test1.xml and test2.xml you should get what I get....just on a smaller scale.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a loop calling writerow:

```
...
with open('results.csv', 'w', newline='') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerow([root.attrib, filename])
    for i in e:
        writer.writerow([i.tag, i.text])
```

Comment: Almost right now, thanks. I've done that and now . Its better but still not including all files in the csv , only the first one. I've added the new code to my original post so you can spot my mistake :)

Comment: Actually what I put before wasn't true. The only output left in the csv is from the last file that was processed.

Comment: Its like the previous csv is overwritten and only the last xml file to be processed is retained

Comment: @Logi_gg: Opening a file in `"w"` mode erase previous content. Use append mode (`"a"` instead of `"w"`) to append to a file.

Comment: Bingo! That's all it was. Knew it was something simple! Thanks

Comment: Last thing ... I hope!! .. I'm getting "mismatched tag" errors when is ending the program. This seems to be from a batch of xml files without any "MatrixSwitch" element. How do I get the program to ignore these and carry on? I'd seen you can sometime do "recover=True" but not had any luck with that

Comment: @Logi_gg: You should enclose the parsing part into a `try` block to ignore an offending file and continue on the next one. Make sure to leave a message to know what files were ignored...

Comment: It was just the one offending file. I've removed it. Last problem is that now its all writing correctly to the csv I've noticed most of the xml files are duplicated 5-10 times each. So the finished csv has around 4000 sets of data, rather than around 900 . Really weird. They are definitely not duplicated in the source folder.